# Laravel 5 Can't Receive / Read Json Format (POST METHOD)?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I've successfully created REST using laravel for GET method. My laravel can't read JSON data, but if i use form-data, the laravel can receive / read JSON normaly. Here's my controller:

```
public function store(){
        $tagihan=new tagihan;
        $tagihan->no_rek_pelanggan=Request::input('no_rek_pelanggan');
        $tagihan->keadaan_meteran=Request::input('keadaan_meteran');
        $tagihan->angka_meteran=Request::input('angka_meteran');
        $success=$tagihan->save();

        if(!$success)
        {
            return Response::json("error saving",500);
        }    
        return Response::json("success",201);
    }`
```

I also add `use Request;` on my controller.

Here's my result when I use form-data

[image: Success when I use form-data]

Here's my result when I use raw (JSON)

[image: Here's my result when I use raw (JSON)]

my laravel can't read / receive JSON data.

JSON I've tried to submit:

```
[{
"id":20,
"no_rek_pelanggan":11117,
"keadaan_meteran":0,
"angka_meteran":600,
"status":0
}]
```

`["tagihan": {
    "id":20,
    "no_rek_pelanggan":11117,
    "keadaan_meteran":0,
    "angka_meteran":600,
    "status":0
}]'`

"tagihan" is my mysql table name.

Comment: what's that `$a` you are using? and check for datatypes as well whether its matched with `db` schema or not

Comment: is no_rek_pelanggan field an integer or varchar or what?
Have you tried 
"no_rek_pelanggan":"11117",

Comment: @Sid : `Request $a` was deleted and still error.
@talhamalik22 : integer used.. still same. laravel can't read.

Comment: SOLVED! There's no problem on my code. Just some mistake on rest client. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? That your request data is always in JSON proper format?

```
public function store(Request $requestData){
    $request = json_encode($requestData);
    //check here if all data is now good
    dd($request);

    $tagihan=new tagihan;
    $tagihan->no_rek_pelanggan=$request->no_rek_pelanggan;
    $tagihan->keadaan_meteran=$request->keadaan_meteran;
    $tagihan->angka_meteran=$request->angka_meteran;
    $success=$tagihan->save();

    if(!$success)
    {
        return Response::json("error saving",500);
    }    
    return Response::json("success",201);
}
```

Comment: The result is `ErrorException in TagihanController.php line 23:
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: SOLVED! There's no problem on my code. Just some mistake on rest client. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $tagihan=new tagihan;
    $tagihan->no_rek_pelanggan=$request->no_rek_pelanggan;
    $tagihan->keadaan_meteran=$request->keadaan_meteran;
    $tagihan->angka_meteran=$request->angka_meteran;
    $success=$tagihan->save();

    if(!$success)
    {
        return Response::json("error saving",500);
    }    
    return Response::json("success",201);
}
```

try like this

Comment: Error returned: `ErrorException in TagihanController.php line 24:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$no_rek_pelanggan`

i also tried `$tagihan->no_rek_pelanggan=$request->input->no_rek_pelanggan;`
returned : `ErrorException in TagihanController.php line 24:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$input`

and try ` $tagihan->no_rek_pelanggan=$request->input('no_rek_pelanggan');`
returned : FatalErrorException in TagihanController.php line 24:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()

Comment: on the top of the controller, add this line `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. Have you included this line?

Comment: yes i have.. added `use Request'  to my controller.

Comment: can you add full line like `use Illuminate\Http\Request` and this line as well `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`

Comment: i've add both. If just use Illuminate\Http\Request laravell returned `ReflectionException in Route.php line 286:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist`

Comment: and what about other one, that facade one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113726/discussion-between-sid-and-danu-akbar).